# Could not parse the remainder '%quiz_id' from '"/quiz/%d/api"%quiz_id'

Tags: django, jinja2

Could not parse the remainder:

```
'%quiz_id'' from "/quiz/%d/api"%quiz_id
```

written in template as

```
{{ "/quiz/%d/api"%quiz_id }}
If quiz_id=2 then it should produce /quiz/2/api
```

Any help?

Comment: That's not how templates work.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You should try using URL template tag.

In your urls you will have something like,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('quiz/<id>/api/', views.retrieve_quiz_view, name='quiz-retrieve')
]
```

And in your templates you will have something like,

```
<a href="{% url 'quiz-retrieve'  quiz.id %}">{{ quiz.title }}</a>
```

Hope that helps!